# How can I redirect my Google App Engine naked domain to www and preserve the URL path

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, google-adsense, google-workspace, google-app-engine

[Google Adsense now requires a file "ads.txt"](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7532444?hl=en) in the root of the domain:

> Upload the file to the root level domain of your site (for example,
>   https://example.com/ads.txt).

I use enom with Google App Engine (python runtime). My main site is with `www` as a CNAME `www.example.com` and a redirect from naked domain to `www` but now I want the naked domain `example.com/ads.txt` to redirect to `www.example.com/ads.txt`.

The problem is that `example.com/ads.txt` redirects without the path to the home page of `www.example.com/`.

I don't understand how to fix it. I don't know if it should be done in the enom console, in the Google G Suite console (where I have enabled the redirect from the naked domain to `www`) or in my web framework (using webapp2 but changing it to flask).

Related problem is that HTTPS for the naked domain does not work (`https://example.com`) and does not redirect, but HTTPS works for the `www` and other subdomains.

How can I proceed? The site is [this one](https://www.koolbusiness.com/) and it is a Google App Engine project.

I enabled the redirect in the google GSuite web console under "domains" where it says:

> Redirect the naked domain `http://example.com` to
>   `http://www.example.com` Change redirect To enable this redirect,
>   you must change the A record with your domain host.

Apparently the above setting once set cannot be undone. I also set the DNS records exactly as stated by Google. The site does respond at www subdomain and does the redirect but the URL path and query are not preserved.

Comment: "in the Google G Suite console (where I have enabled the redirect from the naked domain to www)" - How exactly have you done this? The redirect to `/ads.txt` should be the _same redirect_ not an _additional redirect_?

Comment: @MrWhite I added more information. The background is that I must respond to google from my root path e.g. `http://example.com/ads.txt` but that does not redirect properly (the ads.txt part is dropped during the redirect). It seems like there is no way for me to even check what was the path before the redirect.

Comment: I edited your question to say "URL path" everywhere you had said "query string".  You are confusing the two terms.   `/ads.txt` is the path of the URL.   It could also have a query string with a question mark like `/ads.txt?query=string`, but it sounds like that isn't actually the problem.

Comment: It looks like this [so] question has a solution: [Google App Engine Python Webapp2 301 redirect from www to non-www domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332234/google-app-engine-python-webapp2-301-redirect-from-www-to-non-www-domain) however it will only work if you manage to undo the redirection setting and let your web app handle the requests.

Comment: Having an ads.txt file isn't actually required for Google AdSense.  They are strongly recommending that you create one.  However they are not requiring it.   See [Purpose of ads.txt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124184/purpose-of-ads-txt)

Comment: You appear to have 2 separate redirects occurring on your site, one that preserves the URL-path, the other doesn't. **1.** Non-www to www redirect (`Server: ghs`) that loses the URl-path and **2.** HTTP to HTTPS redirect (`Server: Google Frontend`) that preserves the URL-path. (?)

Comment: So is there a way to make app-engine preserve the URL path? It's okay to modify the app code for me.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's a pity that we are not able to undo the redirection setting. That's the answer the support team gave me.

Comment: @Niklas Why are you using `www` with `CNAME` instead of an `A/AAAA` record?

Comment: @JimmyAdaro I don't remember. Will check and follow up a.s.a.p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your G Suite using the same domain and have turned on the naked domain redirect, you are stuck. I have asked the support, and they don't have a practical answer.

The cause is: G Suites and App Engine uses the same A record and G Suites will rob the routing before App Engine. Then the naked domain redirect by G Suites will replace everything by like `http://www.yourdomain.com/`, dropping any path or query information. There is nothing you can do other than asking Google to fix this. I don't know how to, though.

As a workaround, use another machine or cloud computing service **other than Google Cloud** like Amazon EC2 (I failed with S3 since it does not work well without Route 53), point your naked domain to it, then redirect with a tiny server there.

Or you can stop using G Suites for the site's domain, but I'm not sure if App Engine can handle the naked domain well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I can try and remove the domain completely from G Suite and then add it back again with no naked domain redirect. Or the workaround routing which you describe.